# IMPORTJSON sometimes not getting data even when I use Google Workspace

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch, custom-function

I find an ImportJson on google like this:

```
function IMPORTJSON(json, xpath) {
try{
// /rates/EUR
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var content = res.getContentText();
var json = JSON.parse(content);

var patharray = xpath.split("/");
//Logger.log(patharray);

for(var i=0;i\<patharray.length;i++){
json = json\[patharray\[i\]\];
}

//Logger.log(typeof(json));

if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
return "Node Not Available";
} else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
var tempArr = \[\];

     for(var obj in json){
       tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
     }
     return tempArr;

} else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
return json;
}
}
catch(err){
return "Error getting data";
}
}
```

And I have a method to load status of tracking number as UPS, Fedex...

```
=importjson(join("","http://shipit-api.herokuapp.com/api/carriers/",X4,"/",W4),"activities/0/details")
```

With X4 is carrier name "usps, fedex, ups..."
and W4 is containt tracking number.
Could any way for I just only load status 1 times and use result for each cell containt tracking number?
because now some time my sheet got "Error getting data" and until next days the code will run again

I try to use Google workspace account to run this but still run for some day (when my data have 1000 row have tracking number) it show "Error getting data" again

Comment: Have you tried with [ImportJSON()](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON)?

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you have to spend some time learning about debugging, HTTP requests and error handling in JavaScript / Google Apps Script as the error that you got is a custom error that is not being helpful to understand what is happening.

Start by adding `console.log(err.message, err.stack)` in the `catch` clause:

```js
function IMPORTJSON(json, xpath) {
  try {
    // /rates/EUR
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);

    var patharray = xpath.split("/");
    //Logger.log(patharray);

    for (var i = 0; i\ < patharray.length; i++) {
      json = json\[patharray\[i\]\];
    }

    //Logger.log(typeof(json));

    if (typeof(json) === "undefined") {
      return "Node Not Available";
    } else if (typeof(json) === "object") {
      var tempArr = \ [\];

      for (var obj in json) {
        tempArr.push([obj, json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;

    } else if (typeof(json) !== "object") {
      return json;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message, err.stack);
    return "Error getting data";
  }
}
```

Then use something like thef following function to run / debug the function from the script editor.

```
function debugIMPORTJSON(){
   const X4 = "put here the value of X4";
   const W4 = "put here the value of W4";
   const value = IMPORTJSON(["http://shipit-api.herokuapp.com/api/carriers/",X4,"/",W4].join(""),"activities/0/details");
   console.log(value);
}
```

Once you get the error message you will be in a better position to determine the next steps to find the solution.

Comment: I make debug like you ask and this is error that logger cacth:      Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch. Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch.
    at IMPORTJSON (ImportJSON:10:26)
    at debugIMPORTJSON (ImportJSON:44:18)
    at __GS_INTERNAL_top_function_call__.gs:1:8